# Evaluate trend reversal in Pinescript

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I tried querying reversal in pinescript. Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to be that easy. My script test colors the candles when they are in the range of a reversal. Unfortunately, this does not always work clearly and I get colored several candles. Of course, I would like to achieve the best that only one candle is colored directly on the reversal. Is something like this possible in Pinescript?

```
// Test Highest
highestHigh = ta.highest(high, 10)
lowestLows = ta.lowest(low, 10)

is_high = high >= highestHigh
is_low = low <= lowestLows

highestHigh_bar = ta.highestbars(high, 5)
lowestLows_bar = ta.lowestbars(low, 5)

//is_high_bar = high >= highestHigh_bar
//is_low_bar = low <= lowestLows_bar

//is_high_bar = highestHigh_bar
//is_low_bar = lowestLows_bar


is_high_bar = ta.highest(close, 31)[10] >= ta.highest(close, 10)
is_low_bar = ta.lowest(close, 31)[10] <= ta.lowest(close, 10)

//PmeU = if is_high
    //label.new(bar_index, na, "" + str.tostring(highestHigh), color=color.green, textcolor=color.black, style=label.style_label_down, yloc=yloc.abovebar)

barcolor(is_high ? color.rgb(62, 21, 245) : na)
barcolor(is_low ? color.rgb(223, 19, 250) : na)

//barcolor(is_high_bar ? color.rgb(62, 21, 245) : na)
//barcolor(is_low_bar ? color.rgb(223, 19, 250) : na)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an easy task. People pay tons of money for such indicators which work well.

The problem with such patterns is, you need to wait a few bars to confirm the price action. Then you are already too late.

There are many methods which can help you. One of them is break of structure. You need to identify support and resistance levels. You can do that with the `ta.pivothigh()` and `ta.pivotlow()` functions. After that, you need to look for a break of structure which usually indicates change in trend.

You can combine that with, moving averages, candlestick patterns, momentum etc.